# Not getting value from class

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I am going thru some elements on site and cannot get value of email.

I`ve tried with different selectors.

```
 $data5 =  $html->find('div[class="OglasContactDataRight"]',4)->plaintext; 
   var_dump($data5);
   echo "5:";
   echo $data5;
```

element source from where I am getting this data is:

```
<div class="OglasContactDataRight"><a href="mailto:somemail@gmail.com" class="sup">somemail@gmail.com</a></div>
```

I would like to get plaintext value of a email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could make the selector a bit more specific using `div[class="OglasContactDataRight"] a.sup` and then pass 0 to [find](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual.htm) to get the 0 anchor.

```
$data5 = $html->find('div[class="OglasContactDataRight"] a.sup', 0);
echo $data5->plaintext; // somemail@gmail.com
```

Or if you have multiple you could use a `foreach`:

```
$html->find('div[class="OglasContactDataRight"] a.sup');
foreach ($html->find('div[class="OglasContactDataRight"] a.sup') as $item) {
    echo($item->plaintext);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

$data5 =  $html->find('a.sup',0)->plaintext; 
   Assuming a sup is the first found value